# bootstrap typeahead not working on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-typeahead

mycontroller:

```
@products = Product.all
```

myview:

```
<%= javascript_tag "var products = #{@products.to_json};" %>
<%= form_for @dolist, :html => { :class => 'form-horizontal' } do |f| %>
    <%= f.text_field :product, autofocus: true, placeholder: "product", autocomplete: "off", id: "products", data: {provide: "typeahead"} %>
     <div class="form-actions">
         <%= f.submit 'Submit', :class => 'btn btn-primary' %>
      </div>
<% end %>
```

typeahead is not working for me, i must be missing something.

Answer (score -1):

It seems that you didn't provide `data-source`, `data-source` should be a string that presents an array. like:

```
<input type="text" data-provide="typeahead" data-source="[&quot;Alabama&quot;,&quot;Alaska&quot;,&quot;Arizona&quot;,&quot;Arkansas&quot;]"/>
```

Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bigxiang/fTNwg/

In your view, you can use `@products.to_json`, if it's a correct format.

In complex situation, you can use javascript directly:

```
<%= f.text_field :product, autofocus: true, placeholder: "product", autocomplete: "off", id: "products"%>
<%= javascript_tag "var products = #{@products.to_json};" %>
<script type="text/javascript">            
  $('#products').typeahead({
    source: products
    #other options like events
  });
</script>
```

see document: http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/javascript.html#typeahead